# Error during instantiation of a class within a other class

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to access a class "Skills" and using the class within a other class "Employee" to add skills within the employee. but I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: Skill is not defined
at Employee.js:21

```
 class Skill{
    constructor(sId){
        this.sId = sId;
    }
}
if (localStorage.getItem("Skill") == null) {
    var skillList =[];
    skillList.push(new Skill("Rekruttering"));
    skillList.push(new Skill("Bogføring"));
    skillList.push(new Skill("Engros-salg"));
    skillList.push(new Skill("JavaScript"));

  if(localStorage.getItem("Skill") == null){
      skillListString = JSON.stringify(skillList);
      localStorage.setItem("Skill", skillListString);
  }
else {
    skillList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Skill"));
  }

    constructor(name, gender, department, yy, email, skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.skills = skills;
    }
    addNewSkill(skill){
        this.skills.push(skill);
    }
}


//Employee Database "Localstorage"
if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
    let employeeList = [];
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "2650@mail.dk", new Skill("Sales")));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "1234@email.com"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", "Female", "Sales",1998, "Mail2@mail.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", "Male","IT", 1997, "blabla@mail.dk"));

    if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
        employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList);
        localStorage.setItem("Employee", employeeListString);
        employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
    }
} else {
    employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
    document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
}
```

Comment: Where is `Skill` defined? Also the 6th `skills` parameter of the `Employee` constructor is omitted on some but `addNewSkill` expects it to be defined and have a `push` method.

Comment: I edited the other class in. The two classes are two separate js files

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a non-array object to your `skills` field, and then calling `skills.push` as if it were an array. Simply assign an array instead.

`new Employee(..., [new Skill("Sales")]);`

Comment: `Skill` could extend array or have a push method. I think more importantly the 6th `skills` parameter is omitted in some so it should have a default value.

Comment: When im trying to assign it to an array, im not getting acces to the other class. It uses the id from the "Skills" constructor

Comment: i edited the skills class in, the classes are two different JS files

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen you have no array for `skills` you never create it

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the skills array. So you need to always specify the 6th param and always have it be an array like @junvar says or use a default value (it still needs to be an array when you do specify it, ie `[new Skill("Sales")]`)

```js
class Skill {

  /**
   * @param {string} sId
   */
  constructor(sId){
    this.sId = sId;
  }

}

class Employee {

  /**
   * @param {string} name
   * @param {string} gender
   * @param {string} department
   * @param {number} yy
   * @param {string} email
   * @param {Skill[]} [skills=[]] - initial skills, defaults to empty array
   */
  constructor(name, gender, department, yy, email, skills = []) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.department = department;
    this.email = email;
    this.skills = skills;
  }
  
  /**
   * @param {Skill} skill - new skill to add
   */
  addNewSkill(skill) {
    this.skills.push(skill);
  }

}

const e1 = new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "2650@mail.dk", [new Skill("Sales")]);
e1.addNewSkill(new Skill("JS"));
console.log(e1.skills.map(s => s.sId)); // [ "Sales", "JS" ]

const e2 = new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "1234@email.com"); // only 5 params works because of `skills = []` above
e2.addNewSkill(new Skill("JS"));
console.log(e2.skills.map(s => s.sId)); // [ "JS" ]
```